# Old bathroom “heat lamp fan” has two black wires?

Tags: wiring, bathroom-fixtures, old-house

My old bathroom, exhaust fan, light, and heat lamp is on a three function switch. When you turn on the light it also turns on a “heat lamp fan” and the vanity light and gives power to outlet next to sink. (The heat lamp fan is a fan that pushes air towards the heat lamp and out the receptacle into the bathroom. It has been cut removed in the photo.) In the photo two black wires are capped off these wires were the only two wires to the heat lamp fan I crossed these wires and they short circuited and flipped the breaker. Since the wires are not connected to the fan motor anymore when I flip the switch for the heat lamp it gets no power. Can someone explain how this diagram would look to me. I don’t understand how two hot wires went to the fan?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It isn't two hot wires. It's two undifferentiated wires. The fan motor didn't care which one was hooked up to hot and which one was hooked up to neutral, and since this was inside the device the manufacturer didn't pretend otherwise.

Comment: Why did taking this out of function cause the heat lamp switch to no longer work?

Comment: Something got disconnected that shouldn't have, or burned out when you blew the breaker, or just plain failed. Can't tell which without examining/testing.